# Problems executing script from command line in R. Error message: cannot find path specified

Tags: r, command-line

I have been trying to execute a simple test.R

```
setwd("C:\Users\jdd\Documents")
test <- 2*6598
filename = "test.csv"
write.csv(test,file=filename)
```

Via the following command line command in Windows:

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-2.15.2\bin\R.exe" CMD BATCH   --vanilla --slave "C:\Users\jdd\Documents\test.R"
```

When I execute this I get the following error:

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

I have been trying to work out a solution on the basis of the provided error message, but failed so far. Wondering if somebody can help me so I can execute the script directly from the command line. Thanks

Comment: You sure? R should throw an error about \U being used without hex digits on that `setwd` line.

Comment: Use `setwd("C:\\Users\\jdd\\Documents")` or `setwd("C:/Users/jdd/Documents")`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Removed `setwd()` line and still receive the same error.

Comment: @Jochem Have you considered using Rscript? I don't think R CMD BATCH is recommended anymore. Do you get "no input file" for `"C:\Program Files\R\R-2.15.2\bin\R.exe" CMD BATCH` on its own?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thanks @sebastian-c! I tried to use RScript, which I investigated before. However, the problem was a different one. Appears that in my installation there is a `R.exe` and `Rscript.exe` file in `.\bin`, but also one in `.\bin\x64`. The first one is not working properly, but the second one is. The comment made by @Roland is very important as well, since once working I got this error message!

The following command did the job:

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-2.15.2\bin\x64\Rscript.exe" "C:\Users\jdd\Documents\test.R"
```

and the corrected text.R is:

```
setwd("C:\\Users\\jdd\\Documents")
test <- 2*6598
filename = "test.csv"
write.csv(test,file=filename)
```

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned [here](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=15677), it might has something to do with 64bit version of R.
The problem is that Rscript.exe itself is attempting to access a missing file on the system. The obvious fix is explicitly add 'x64' to the path of the other Rscript.exe that was installed:

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-2.15.2\bin\x64\Rscript.exe" --version
R scripting front-end version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
```