# R Startup on Windows10- "The system cannot find the path specified." message. How can I find the path?

Tags: r, windows, startup

This is not a big deal; everything seems to be working, but I'm bothered by a message that I receive every time I start R on Windows 10:

```
C:\devl\temp>R
**The system cannot find the path specified.**

R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05) -- "Action of the Toes"
Copyright (C) 2019 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
```

I've reinstalled it, changed paths in Rprofile.site, messed with my path. I can directly run the R executable:

```
C:\R\R-3.6.1\bin>.\x64\R.exe
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

and still get the message.

Anyways, I just want to understand R's startup sequence a bit better, so I'd appreciate any advice on where to look to find that path R is trying to open at startup.

**Update**
@Pepv's link led me to the startup package's `startup(debug=TRUE)` function. After doing a bit of cleanup, below is the full output. The answer has to be staring me in the face now.

```
C:\Users>R
The system cannot find the path specified.

R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05) -- "Action of the Toes"
Copyright (C) 2019 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

[1] "I'm the Rprofile.site in the R installation directory!"
[1] "I am the .Rprofile in C:/devl"
> startup::startup(debug = TRUE)
0.001s: System information:
0.007s: - R_HOME: 'C:/R/R-3.6.1' (existing folder)
0.012s: - R call: C:\R\R-3.6.1/bin/x64/Rterm.exe
0.017s: - Current directory: 'C:/Users'
0.022s: - User's home directory: '~' => 'C:\devl' (existing folder)
0.028s: - Search path: '.GlobalEnv', 'package:stats', 'package:graphics', 'package:grDevices', 'package:utils', 'package:datasets', 'package:methods', 'Autoloads', 'package:base'
0.044s: - Loaded namespaces: 'compiler', 'startup', 'graphics', 'utils', 'grDevices', 'stats', 'datasets', 'methods', 'base'
0.055s: The following has already been processed by R:
0.061s: - R_ENVIRON: ''
0.063s: - R_ENVIRON_USER: ''
0.068s: - R_DEFAULT_PACKAGES: '' (= 'base,methods,datasets,utils,grDevices,graphics,stats')
0.078s: - R_LIBS: 'C:\devl\Rpackages'
0.083s: - R_LIBS_SITE: ''
0.086s: - R_LIBS_USER: 'C:\devl\Rpackages'
0.090s: - R_PROFILE: ''
0.095s: - R_PROFILE_USER: 'C:\devl\.Rprofile' (1 lines; 42 bytes)
0.105s: - 'C:/R/R-3.6.1/etc/Rprofile.site' (2 code lines; 619 bytes)
0.117s: - 'C:\devl\.Rprofile' (1 code lines; 42 bytes)
0.124s: startup::startup()-specific processing ...
0.130s: Found startup directory '~/.Renviron.d'.
0.145s: Processing 1 Renviron files ...
0.153s:  - 'C:\devl/.Renviron.d/.Renviron' (0 lines; 0 bytes) setting 0 environment variables
0.164s: Processing 1 Renviron files ... done
0.177s: Found startup directory 'C:\devl\.Rprofile.d'.
0.188s: Processing 1 Rprofile files ...
0.196s:  - 'C:\devl\.Rprofile.d/.Rprofile' (1 code lines; 30 bytes)
[1] "I am in .Rprofile.d"
0.208s: Processing 1 Rprofile files ... done
0.216s: - unloading the 'startup' package
0.222s: - Search path: '.GlobalEnv', 'package:stats', 'package:graphics', 'package:grDevices', 'package:utils', 'package:datasets', 'package:methods', 'Autoloads', 'package:base'
0.238s: - Loaded namespaces: 'compiler', 'graphics', 'utils', 'grDevices', 'stats', 'datasets', 'methods', 'base'
0.250s: startup::startup()-specific processing ... done
0.257s: The following will be processed next by R:
0.262s: - R_HISTFILE: ''
0.274s: - .First(): no such function on search()
0.279s: - Remaining packages per R_DEFAULT_PACKAGES to be attached by base::.First.sys() (in order):
```

**Update 2**
Or maybe not. Rterm.exe does not trigger the message, and per [this source](https://www.r-bloggers.com/rinwin-character-eaten-by-cmd-or-powershell-r-exe-or-rterm-exe/), "R (as opposed to Rterm) is a small .exe program that does a little
argument parsing, then runs Rterm." Even R.exe --help triggers the message so this must have something to do with the actual R.exe argument parsing. Close to closing this question.

Comment: Try putting a `cat` statement at the beginning and at the end of your .Rprofile file to try to narrow it down.  Also from Windows cmd line enter `set R` to display any environment variables that might be associated with R.

Comment: Good ideas. I put some extra cat statements in and I can see a lot about what's going on with startup::startup(debug=TRUE). Given that R.exe --version, shows the message, it seems like it has to be central to R.exe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When R starts, the following user-specific setup takes place:
>
> The first .Renviron file found on the R startup search path is
>   processed. The search path is (in order): (i)
>   Sys.getenv("R_ENVIRON_USER"), (ii) ./.Renviron, and (iii) ~/.Renviron.
>   The format of this file is one ENV_VAR=VALUE statement per line, cf.
>   ?.Renviron. NOTE: Some environment variables must be set already in
>   this step in order to be acknowledged by R, i.e. it is too late to set
>   some of them in Step 2 and Step 3 below.
>
> The first .Rprofile file found on the R startup search path is
>   processed. The search path is (in order): (i)
>   Sys.getenv("R_PROFILE_USER"), (ii) ./.Rprofile, and (iii) ~/.Rprofile.
>   The format of this file must be a valid R script (with a trailing
>   newline), cf. ?.Rprofile.
>
> If the .Rprofile file (in Step 2) calls startup::startup() then the
>   following will also take place:
>
> a. The first .Renviron.d directory on the R startup search path is
>   processed. The search path is (in order): (i)
>   paste0(Sys.getenv("R_ENVIRON_USER"), ".d"), (ii) ./.Renviron.d, and
>   (iii) ~/.Renviron.d. The format of these files should be the same as
>   for .Renviron. NOTE: Some environment variables must be set already in
>   Step 1 above in order to be acknowledged by R.
>
> b. A set of handy R options that can be use in Step 3c are set. Their
>   names are prefixed startup.session. - see
>   ?startup::startup_session_options for details.
>
> c. The first .Rprofile.d directory found on the R startup search path
>   is processed. The search path is (in order): (i)
>   paste0(Sys.getenv("R_PROFILE_USER"), ".d"), (ii) ./.Rprofile.d, and
>   (iii) ~/.Rprofile.d. The format of these files should be the same as
>   for .Rprofile, that is, they must be valid R scripts.
>
> d. If no errors occur above, the startup package will be unloaded,
>   leaving no trace of itself behind, except for R options
>   startup.session.* set in Step 3b - these will be erased if
>   startup::startup() is called with keep = NULL.

Info extracted from https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/startup/vignettes/startup-intro.html

**EDIT:**

Check this solution, maybe it also works for you: [Problems executing script from command line in R. Error message: cannot find path specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14956887/problems-executing-script-from-command-line-in-r-error-message-cannot-find-pat)

Comment: Thanks, you definitely gave me some ideas. I made sure the environment variables you wrote about were set and even created an .Rprofile.d and .Renviron.d directories and put .Rprofile and .Renviron files in them. Still getting the darn message. Will check out the startup-intro doc you linked to.

Comment: You're welcome. Check the edit on my answer, maybe it helps you.

Comment: It's got to be related. I just realized that when I run Rterm.exe instead of R.exe, there's no 'The system cannot find the path specified', even though R.exe is supposed to be the latest and greatest. Like Ohad mentions in his error, it must be that R.exe is trying to access some missing file on the system. Maybe it's from a ghost of R past. I'll leave this question open for another day or so and then close it down.

Comment: Hey here's another situation where someone switched to Rterm from R.exe: https://www.r-bloggers.com/rinwin-character-eaten-by-cmd-or-powershell-r-exe-or-rterm-exe/

Comment: A year later (Iam running )R-3.6.3 is still popping out that same error message in my case even before R.exe will start at all because I dropped some additional startup options. 
`The system cannot find the path specified.
Fatal error: you must specify '--save', '--no-save' or '--vanilla'
`
Rterm.exe also runs without any 'cannot find the path specified' messages. 
What I find weird is that this started popping up only lately.